# Extracting $content value from JSON in "File Content" when using the SharePoint "Get file content using path" action

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm using the "Get file content using path" to retrieve a PDF document from SharePoint.

[image]

In the subsequent "Set variable" action I then need to access the value of the $content property to build a json request like so
[image]

This is currently not working for me as I am getting the following error in the "Parse JSON" action at runtime:

***BadRequest**. The property 'content' must be of type JSON in the 'ParseJson' action inputs, but was of type 'application/pdf'.*

The schema for my Parse JSON action looks a s follow:

[image]

How can get the value of $content property from the "File Content" action output?

By the way below does not work

[image]

as my JSON ends up like this:

```
  "Attachments": [
    {
      "AttachmentData": {
        "$content-type": "application/pdf",
        "$content": "JVBERi0xLjQN......."
      },
      "AttachmentName": "Hollow.pdf"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Hello, AttachmentData need to be set to the value of the $content. So, the sub-fields “$content-type” and “$content” should not be present. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can use the expression `outputs('Get_file_content_using_path')?['body']?['$content']` to get the value of `$content` property from the "File Content" action output. Please refer to the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This seems promising. I will try it and respond with an update. Cheers